# In jhipster how to integrate a angular admin themes template instead of default one

Tags: angular, jhipster

In jhipster how to integrate an angular admin themes template instead of default one, we bought a admin theme from ThemeForest, its possible to integrate web application instead of default jhipster admin template

Comment: The effort will depend on which theme you chose, if it uses Bootstrap with same version then it should be easy, otherwise it'll mean you can throw away the UI code generated by JHipster.

Comment: You can improve this question by posting some code showing us what you have tried.